# How to hide a function of all but visible to the owner

Tags: contract-development, dapps, ethereum-wallet-dapp

How to hide a function of all but visible to the owner.
For example there is a function:

```
function freezeAccount(address target, bool freeze)
```

How to hide it from others.

Comment: what do you mean by hide??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some [visibility specifiers](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#visibility-and-accessors) in Solidity, but none of them allows to "hide function from others".

> Everything that is inside a contract is visible to all external observers. Making something private only prevents other contracts from accessing and modifying the information, but it will still be visible to the whole world outside of the blockchain.

So, you can't *hide* function, but you can *restrict access*.

This is usually done with [function modifiers](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/structure-of-a-contract.html#function-modifiers):

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
import "github.com/ethereum/solidity/std/owned.sol";

contract Test is owned {
    function freezeAccount(address target, bool freeze) onlyowner {
       // ...
    }
}
```

`onlyowner` function modifier is defined in [solidity's standard library](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/061b50ae19b0f8b9dcffc8dab5f08c4e26e884fb/std/owned.sol).

For more information see [Restricting Access](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/common-patterns.html#restricting-access) section in Solidity docs.